# What is the most efficient way to get a subset of items in a Java Object?

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have the following class;

```
public class RSSFeed implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int _itemcount = 0;
    private List<RSSItem> _itemlist;

    RSSFeed() {
        _itemlist = new Vector<RSSItem>(0);
    }

    void addItem(RSSItem item) {
        _itemlist.add(item);
        _itemcount++;
    }
    public void removeItem(RSSItem item) {
        _itemlist.remove(item);
        _itemcount--;
    }
    public void shuffleList() {
        Collections.shuffle(_itemlist);
    }
    public RSSItem getItem(int location) {
        return _itemlist.get(location);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return _itemcount;
    }
    public void reverseList(){Collections.reverse(_itemlist);};

}
```

I can create an object of this class as follows;

```
public static RSSFeed feed;
```

Now, I want another object like `public static RSSFeed **feed1**`; where feed1 contains items 3 to 20 of the big object `feed`. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: FYI if you're really concerned about efficiency, use ArrayList instead of Vector.

Comment: Ok, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the top three from the `List`, you can iterate the `List` `_itemlist` and create a temporary `List` and return the temporary list.

```
public List<RSSItem> getTopThree() {
    if(_itemlist != null){
        List<RSSItem> temp = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
        for (RSSItem item : _itemlist) {
            temp.add(item);
            if(temp.size() == 3)
                break;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

An optimisation would be to pre create and store the items as a field in the class `RSSFeed`.

According to **@MouseEvents** sugestion, you can also use [`sublist`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) method of the `ArrayList`. See the code below.

```
public List<RSSItem> getTopThree() {
    if (_itemlist != null) {
        int end = _itemlist.size() < 3 ? _itemlist.size() : 3;
        return _itemlist.subList(0, end);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would rather use sublist().

Comment: @MouseEvent Great suggestion! Wasn't actually aware of such a method. Thanks a bunch :)